# Using a scalar as a condition in an OLE DB data flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, scalar, dataflow

I am having a problem with a data flow task in an ssis package i am trying to build. The objective of the package is to update tables situated in our local server using a connection to a distant server containing the source of the data, through a vpn connection.

There are no problems for tables which are re-downloaded entirely.

But some of the tables must be updated for real. What I mean is they're not re-downloaded. For each of those tables, I have to check the maximum value of the date column in our local server (int YYYMMDD type) and ask the package to download only the data added after that date.

I thought about using a scalar (@MAXDATE for ex) but the issue is, I have to declare this scalar in a session with our local server, and I cannot use it as a condition in an OLE DB Source task, because the latter implies a new session, this time with the distant server.

I can only view the database on the distant server and import it. So no way to create a table on it.

I hope it is clear enough. Would you have any tips to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Ozgur

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using an execute SQL Task, a Data Flow task and one variable. I would probably add some error checking just in case no value is found on the local system, but that depends very much on what might go wrong.

Assuming VS2008

Declare a package level variable of type datetime. Give it an appropriate default value.

Create an Execute SQL Task with a query that returns the appropriate date value. On the first page of the properties window, make sure the Result Set is set to "Single Row." On the Result Set page, map the date column to the package variable.

Create a Data Flow task. In the OLE DB Data Source, write your query to include a question mark for the incoming date value. "and MaxDate>?". Now when you click on the Paramaters button, you should get a pop-up that allows you to map "Parameter0" to your package level variable.